# Is it possible to create a freebsd 10 or 11 jail in freebsd 9?

Tags: freebsd, jails

My title question is exactly my question : is it possible to create a freebsd 10 or 11 jail into a freebsd 9 instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jail and the host system will both share the same kernel. So:

- **Old jail, recent host**: Running an outdated jail on a newer host should not cause any issue (the FreeBSD kernel will ensure retro-compatibility, enabled by default even for pre-FreeBSD 8 kernel as a kernel compilation option),
- **Recent jail, old host**: I would not try to run a newer jail on an older host. This would mean running a FreeBSD 10/11 environment using a FreeBSD 9 kernel which is definitively **not** recommended.

So, in your case, *the answer is no*, it is not possible (even if it may install successfully it will most likely lead you directly to a wall).